# Storing User Input Integers in an Array

Tags: c#

I am trying to ask the user to input 10 numbers. After receiving the numbers, I am storing them in an array followed by printing the array. I came up with the following code to do the task but it is not printing the array.

Also feel that I may have rattled on way too much code for a simple task. Do note that I am very new to c# thus not familiar with advanced stuff or possibly even most of basic stuff. Even the "convert.toInt32", I adopted from reading around and not taught in class yet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test_Array
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            int b;
            int c;
            int d;
            int e;
            int f;
            int g;
            int h;
            int i;
            int j; 

            Console.WriteLine("Please input 10 numbers. Press 'ENTER' after each number.");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            f = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            g = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] newArray = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j};

            Console.WriteLine(newArray);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a loop that runs 10 times instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToString` method of arrays (which is what `Console.WriteLine` is calling in your code) isn't overloaded to print out the contents of the array.  It leaves the basic `object` implementation of just printing the type name.

You need to manually iterate the array and print out the individual values (or use a method that will do that for you).

I.e.

```
foreach(var item in array)
    Console.WriteLine(item)
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", array));
```

Comment: While the 1st technique is quite routine, the 2nd technique is quite interesting.

Answer (score 7):

use a `for` loop.

```
int[] newArray = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
{
    newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You can use the same loop to display as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(newArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: The array is constructed properly (albeit not concisely); the issue is printing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] rollno = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the 10 numbers");
        for (int s = 0; s < 9; s++)
        {
            rollno[s] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            rollno[s] +=  110;

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of first 10 numbers is : {0}", rollno[j]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify things a lot with the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int newArray = new int[10];

    Console.WriteLine("Please input 10 numbers. Press 'ENTER' after each number.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The values you've entered are:");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", newArray));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```